# Cucumber wont accept Capybara Minitest Spec assertions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, minitest

I'm using Cucumber with Capybara in Rails 4.2, but I'm not using RSpec. I've been sticking with Minitest. I've been using minitest:spec in most of my tests.

Whenever I try to use make an assertion with minitest or minitest:spec syntax in a Cucumber step I get an error saying the assertion method is undefined. For example this step:

```
Then (/^the state selector has no states$/) do
  page.wont_have_selector(".my-css-class", :visible)
end
```

gives this error

```
undefined method `refute_selector' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

(`page.wont_have_selector` is the minitest:spec syntax for the minitest method `refute_selector`)

I have a file `features/support/minitest.rb` with this content

```
require 'minitest'
require "minitest/rails/capybara"
require "minitest/spec"

module MiniTestAssertions

  def self.extended(base)
    base.extend(MiniTest::Assertions)
    base.assertions = 0
  end

  attr_accessor :assertions

end

World(MiniTestAssertions)
```

Here is my test section of Gemfile

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'mocha', require: false
  gem 'cucumber-rails', require: false
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters'
  gem 'minitest-rails-capybara'
  gem 'minitest-spec-rails'
  gem 'capybara_minitest_spec'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'poltergeist'
end
```

the `Gemfile.lock` includes the following

```
capybara (2.4.4)
capybara_minitest_spec (1.0.5)
cucumber (1.3.20)
cucumber-rails (1.4.2)
minitest (5.7.0)
minitest-capybara (0.7.2)
minitest-metadata (0.5.3)
minitest-rails (2.2.0)
minitest-rails-capybara (2.1.1)
minitest-spec-rails (5.2.2)
rails (4.2.1)
```

**Edit**

It is only Capybara specific Minitest assertions that are not recognised in the Cucumber step file. If I change the step content to this:

```
assert true
refute false
```

then it passes. Also the Capybara Minitest assertions work fine in the `test/features` directory for doing integration testing outside Cucumber.

I think I have to add something to `features/suport/minitest.rb` so that the Capybara Minitest assertions get added to the Cucumber World, but I don't know what it is.

**Edit**

It's actually only the spec version of Capybara's minitest assertions that are giving the problem. If I change the content of the step to this:

```
refute_selector(".my-css-class", :visible)
```

then it works.

**Edit**

I think it's [bug #10](https://github.com/ordinaryzelig/capybara_minitest_spec/issues/10) in capybara_minitest_spec gem that I got reopened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code into `features/support/env.rb`

```
Before do
  Thread.current[:current_spec] = self
end
```

This is from [ordinaryzelig's fix](https://github.com/ordinaryzelig/capybara_minitest_spec/pull/16) for capybara_minitest_spec to add support for Cucumber.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
require 'capybara/cucumber'
```

in your minitest.rb.  If that causes problems because it requires 'capybara/rspec/matchers' (although that file doesn't actually need rspec) then you could just do

```
World(Capybara::DSL)
```

and then implement whatever Before and After hooks you need for your testing environment (see [cucumber.rb](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/cucumber.rb) )

Comment: I tried putting both those lines of code into `minitest.rb` but it seems to have no effect

Comment: The native Capybara mothods work fine as do the normal minitest assertions. I think what is missing is the assertions provided by the gem [minitest-capybara](https://github.com/wojtekmach/minitest-capybara). I've tried adding `World(Capybara::Assertions)` but that also seems to have no effect.

Comment: Rereading your error description, I think maybe you do have the methods included, but it's really a question of why they're being called on nil

Comment: You're right! I've just realised if I put in the step `refute_selector(".my-css-class", :visible)` it works! So it must be to do with the gem that lets me use spec format with Minitest with Capybara